# Having issues with Facebook and LinkedIn Social Sharing

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, facebook-share, salesforce-communities

This one has been driving me crazy!

I"m trying to get social sharing to work on Facebook and Linked in for my business. The site in question is [www.helio.com.au](http://www.helio.com.au) - i've got all of the og:foobar tags in the header but for some reason they are not being picked up by facebook or linkedIn

Here is a link to the LinkedIn inspector

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/www.helio.com.au

- Note that linkedin doesn't find the image

And here is one for facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=www.helio.com.au

facebook says the image has an invalid content type, it's also pulling the wrong URL and I can't figure out where from.

What stupid mistake have I made?

The site is built on salesforce communities

Comment: This is what your server sends back to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helio.com.au%2F . Why you send back that we have no idea.

Comment: Strange, as if you view the source of the HTML at helio.com.au that is not what we have in our headers. Does facebook Cache the data?

Comment: If you look at the debug page you redirect Facebook three times. And no Facebook doesn't cache

Comment: I am getting an XML response saying access denied, when I try to request your og:image in my browser - the Facebook scraper likely gets a similar response. With images hosted on Amazon S3, you'll have to go and check your access setting there.

Comment: @CBroe Facebook is picking up the wrong value from my og:image tag. I removed the wrong image from S3 to see if that might trigger FB to go and find the right one - hence the XML response. Issue seems to be on my end, as WizKid pointed out it could be related to the redirects. Going to see if unravelling that does the trick. Thanks